# Linq: implicit filtering in C# .NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have a DAL layer based on the Repository pattern, which means I have some BaseRepository with the basic generic implementation.
I also have the specified classes which use this BaseRepository by inheritance.

Now I need to restrict the filtering based on some userId condition.
I can't do it excplicitly, I must do it implicitely and this is the question.

So for the explicit filtering, I could something like this:

Change the method in the Base class:

```
public T GetById(object id, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    return _dbSet.Where(predicate).Find(id);
}
```

And then do something like this in the class which uses it:

```
public User GetById(Guid id)
{
    return userRepository.Where(p=>...).GetById(id);
}
```

But this restriction is too obvious for the developers.
Is there a way to make a restriction which is not or at least not so much obvious?

Comment: *"too obvious for the developers"* - It's not clear to me what you even mean by that.  Does your code fail in some way?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: He wants to hide that he is filtering the result to the developers... I think this is a very bad idea. The method will not do what you are expecting to do.

Comment: What is the sql server version you are using?

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is not possible, at least not by only using code.  The filtering has to explicitly happen at some point, and the best you could possibly do is obfuscate it. But the developer will be able to still find it.

One option you do have is to create a view in Sql Server which is performing the filtering and just use linq to query that view.  The only potential downside to doing that is that the view is read only.